# NIS users suddenly can't login to SSH

Tags: nis

I've recently added a new (client) server to my NIS. For a month or so this worked fine, but since today I suddenly can't login through SSH anymore. Some other services (e.g. IMAP) on the same server work fine. The other NIS client seems to work fine.

The SSH session is terminated immediately after successful login:

```
some.nis.user@nismaster:~$ ssh faultyserv
some.nis.usern@faultyserv's password:
Connection to faultyserv closed by remote host.
Connection to faultyserv closed.
```

`/etc/log/auth.log` contains:

```
Aug 31 12:42:22 faultyserv sshd[27909]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user some.nis.user by (uid=0)
Aug 31 12:42:22 faultyserv sshd[27909]: fatal: login_get_lastlog: Cannot find account for uid 1234
```

If I set `UseLogin yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I can login, but get a weird shell:

```
I have no name!@faultyserv:~$ pwd
/home/s/some.nis.user
I have no name!@faultyserv:~$ sudo echo
sudo: unknown uid 1234: who are you?
I have no name!@faultyserv:~$ id some.nis.user
uid=1234 gid=1975(some.nis.user) groups=4294967295,2177(somegroup),/*snip a long grouplist*/
```

I think there is something wrong with the NIS, but have no idea how to fix this, does anyone have an idea?

My `/etc/nsswitch.conf` contains (among more entries without nis):

```
passwd:         files nis
group:          files nis
shadow:         files nis
netgroup:       nis
```

Comment: When I started learning *nix in 1997 (and IMAP didn't exist), NIS was more visible, but clearly it was then an obsolete system on it's way out.  As such I put no effort into it, so I can't answer your question except to say that maybe you should look at alternatives?

Comment: The only real alternative is LDAP, which is more advanced, but also more complicated. However it is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Your first port of call should be to run `ypcat` on the `passwd.byname` and `passwd.byuid` maps. If either of them fails, or if they contain incorrect or inconsistent data, then you have a place to start debugging.

Comment: If you have a `yptest` command, use it.

Comment: NIS is still very useful under the right conditions.  It persists because when correctly set up, it generally just works.  LDAP is nearly-criminally tetchy.

Comment: @aecolley Thanks, that showed me that the `passwd.byuid` map only contained users local to `faultyserv`, leading me to the solution posted below.

Comment: LDAP is the usual recommendation.  I haven't gone down this route, but I've seen freeipa/kerberos recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the `passwd.byuid` map wasn't transferred.

Running `yppush passwd.byuid` on `nismaster` gave a timeout error and generated the following in `faultyserv`'s `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Sep  1 09:51:37 faultyserv ypserv[2038]: refuse to transfer passwd.byuid from <ip>, master is faultyserv.mydomain.com)
```

The slave server had the incorrect master server specified:

```
# ypwhich -m
services.byservicename nismaster
group.bygid nismaster
group.byname nismaster
protocols.bynumber nismaster
services.byname nismaster
hosts.byname nismaster
netgroup.byhost nismaster
rpc.bynumber nismaster
passwd.byuid faultyserv.mydomain.com
netgroup nismaster
ypservers nismaster
shadow.byname faultyserv.mydomain.com
passwd.byname nismaster
hosts.byaddr nismaster
protocols.byname nismaster
rpc.byname nismaster
netgroup.byuser nismaster
netid.byname faultyserv.mydomain.com
```

Re-running `/usr/lib/yp/ypinit -s nismaster` on `faultyserv` fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

This can sometimes happen on Debian systems because of the use of

```
# shadowconfig on
```

Which puts sensitive password hashes in the shadow files and rewrites the passwd and group file with identical bland 'x' entries.

Before you rebuild the passwd and group files, you must do this **on the NIS master**

```
# shadowconfig off
```

On Debian that is

```
# cd /var/lib/yp
# make all
```

Don't forget the special entries you have to add to passwd and group on the **clients**, here is the passwd entry, (after the postgres one).

```
postgres:x:115:124:PostgreSQL administrator,,,:/var/lib/postgresql:/bin/bash
+::::::
```

Here is the group one, after the sambashare.

```
sambashare:x:125:
+:::
```

As well as the /etc/nsswitch.conf mentions for "nis"

Comment: The password hashes will be distributed around your network with NIS. This is known to be insecure. For small clusters on a single physically secure site, this might not be an issue.

Distributed across multiple sites, I would recommend you take on LDAP because there is a PAM LDAP module.